# How do I make crosshair in Roblox studio for a better mobile experience?

Tags: roblox

#### How do I make crosshair in Roblox studio for a better mobile experience?

The problem is there are no mouse on phones. Clicking with fingers is impossible of hitting the target which is far away.

While on PC you can just do that easily. Also on PC the mouse stays in the center. So I need a crosshair like in CS:GO (by the way the camera is always at first person and both of the scripts are in a tool) and when player presses a button for example near the jump button then the player that was under the crosshair gets damage of 25

Here are the scripts ( Lua ):

LocalScript:

```
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    print("hello world")
    script.Parent.RemoteEvent:FireServer(mouse.Hit.p)
end)
```

Script:

```
script.Parent.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, mousePos)
    
    local reycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
    reycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = {player.Character}
    reycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
    
    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(script.Parent.Handle.Position,(mousePos - script.Parent.Handle.Position)*1000, reycastParams)
    
    if raycastResult then
        local hitPart = raycastResult.Instance
        local model = hitPart:FindFirstAncestorOfClass("Model")
        
        if model then
            if model:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                model.Humanoid.Health -= 25
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

You don't have to read this it tells me to describe what I tried but the only thing I tried is looking in the internet. I didn't find anything.